# Почему не выключается ноутбук (linux mint 18.1 cinnamon 64 bit)?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, ос, hp

Установил себе linux mint 18.1, но возникла проблема с выключением. Когда выключаю - ноут гаснет на секунды 3-4 а потом опять включается. Ноутбук hp probook 4540s. Раньше на ноуте были mint 17, ubuntu, elementary, win 7/10 - проблем не было подобных.

Comment: простое решение - поставьте назад убунту. Сложное решение - откройте консоль, выполните команду dmesg (после нескольких "неудачных" попыток выключиться) и посмотрите, что там мешает.

Comment: Вот [тут](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296653/rebooting-instead-of-shutdown-on-linux-mint) есть как минимум два решения для вашего вопроса.

Comment: Причину выяснил, когда отключаю wifi нормально выключается. Буду смотреть в сторону wake on lan или что-то вроде того. И спасибо Роман, почитаю материал по ссылке.

Comment: Ой, вам надо смотреть не столько в дистрибутив, сколько в версию используемых драйверов Wi-Fi. Часто это соответствует версии ядра.